# What is the difference between AppleScript version and AppleScript Studio version?

Tags: applescript, system-information

Testing what can be done with `System Events` I noticed when pulling `system info`:

**AppleScript Version:**

```
tell application "System Events" to return AppleScript version of (get system info)
```

**AppleScript Studio Version:**

```
tell application "System Events" to return AppleScript Studio version of (get system info)
```

there was a difference returned.  When I researched the site I didn't see this asked and I haven't found an answer on Apple discussion.  So what is the difference between the two?

Comment: Just an FYI... No need for using "Tell" statements with that command.  In script editor, simply use the command "system info" and the result will show you the results from both of your examples plus more

Comment: It's a force of habit when coding very long apps and noticing at times there is an issue when calling different commands from System Events and Finder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first line of code simply returns the version of the AppleScript *language* currently in use. You can also see it under **Script Editor** → **Preferences** → **General** → **Default Language**.

As for **AppleScript Studio**, this is what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript#Related_scripting_issues) has to say about it:

> **AppleScript Studio**
>   A framework for attaching Cocoa interfaces to
>   AppleScript applications, part of the Xcode package in Mac OS X 10.4
>   and 10.5, now deprecated in favor of AppleScriptObjC.

— From *AppleScript: the definitive guide, 2nd edition*

In essence, it was what you used for creating AppleScript applications in Xcode.